# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'R4.Services.TaskService' while attempting to activate 'R4.Services.CustomerService'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, invalidoperationexception

I generated a C#-Client with nswag studio. Now I'm calling a function of this client, that sets the tasks of a customer to done, if the customer is deleted.

If I call this function I will always run into this error message:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'R4.Services.TaskService' while attempting to activate
> 'R4.Services.CustomerService'.

I've already looked for ways to solve it and I know the error's reason, but I don't know how I can solve it. No post or page has helped me to solve it.

This is my code:

**The configure-function to register the class in the DI-Container:**

```
public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
            services.AddScoped<IBaseService<Task>, TaskService>();
            services.AddScoped<IBaseService<Customer>, CustomerService>();
}
```

This is the Customer-Service class:

```
public class CustomerService: BaseService<Customer>
{
   private readonly TaskService _taskService;
   public CustomerService(TaskService taskService){
      _taskService = taskService;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this line

```
 public CustomerService(TaskService taskService)
```

Then `CustomerService` wants to use the **service** of type `TaskService`

if we then look at your configure method we see:

```
services.AddScoped<IBaseService<Task>, TaskService>();
```

The documentation states that this is

> AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)

So you see that the first definition is the `TService`which you have defined as `IBaseService<Task>` .

But, in your configure method you don't have any definitions of the type `TaskService` which your class is expecting.  You have instead `IBaseService<Task>`. And in your class you have instead defined that the class should receive the Implementation (TaskService).

So then you have several options:

Change your class to be

```
public CustomerService(IBaseService<Task> taskService)
{
    _taskService = taskService as TaskService;
}
```

or maybe a better approach might be:

Create a new Service

```
public class ITaskService: IBaseService<Task> {} ....
```

then change TaskService to implement ITaskService

```
public class TaskService: ITaskService ....
```

then define in your configure method

```
services.AddScoped<ITaskService, TaskService>();
```

and your class definition to use `ITaskService`

```
private readonly ITaskService _taskService;
   public CustomerService(ITaskService taskService){
      _taskService = taskService;
   }
```

That way, you could also have more services which inherit from IBaseService in the future, if needed.

Comment: Thank you Jason. Now I've understood how I can solve this.